# Process exited with code 255 when running on command prompt through TeamCity

Tags: windows, command-line, teamcity

The following command

```
@Set "installed_version=" & @(FOR /F %a IN ('curl 192.168.1.151:5000/getversion') DO @SET installed_version=%a)
```

is failing when running on a Windows agent in Teamcity with error

> ) was unexpected at this time. Process exited with code 255

However, the same command runs smoothly when running on a command prompt on my local Windows 10 machine. The teamcity agent is a Windows Server 2008 R2, version 6.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, `%` has to be escaped when in a bat file, so it should be `%%`.
At the same time, in Kotlin DSL `%` also needs to be escaped, so we end up with `%%%%`.